# On definitions of interactions in thermodynamics—changing the energy of a closed system without work or heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, interactions

On page 22 of his [famous textbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamics_and_an_Introduction_to_Thermostatistics) on thermodynamics, [Callen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Callen) asks us to consider a particular gas (a simple $(N,V,U)$ system) enclosed in a cylinder. Callen then tells us that

> a small paddle is installed inside the system and is driven by an external motor[...]. The motor exerts a torque, driving, the paddle at an angular velocity $\omega$, and the pressure of the gas (at constant volume) is observed to increase at a rate given by [some expression].

The expression in question then lets us determine the change in energy $U$ of the system by considering the energy lost by this paddle/motor system.

With respect to this problem, but also in general, how do we define the type of energy given to the system? Callen makes the following remark in a footnote on a later page:

> Note that the energy output of the motor is delivered to the system as energy that cannot be classified either as work or as heat-it is a non-quasistatic transfer of energy.

It's not clear to me why the process being non-quasistatic should imply that we cannot classify it as work or heat. Of course, it being nonquasistatic means we can't *compute* the work done using system/equilibrium variables, but that should have no bearing on whether it's work (or heat transfer)? I had thought that changes of the internal energy $U$ could only be achieved by species transfer (changing $N$), by heat transfer, or by work (where one can generalize work for non-PV systems), but Callen seems to suggest that this is not the case?

Comment: In general, words can describe, but not substitute the actual physics. My take, as you seem to have already guessed, is that work IS BEING DONE. Just not in the textbook thermodynamic sense. There is no quasi-static change in P, V, T, and no equation of state and what-not can describe it. This doesn't change the physics at work, maybe Callen just so happens to be strict about his linguistics not to confuse the reader (imagine thinking such a process was quasi-static!)

Answer (score 5):

A recurring theme in Callen is **equilibrium**:

*"Thermodynamics seeks to describe...simple, static equilibrium states
to which systems eventually evolve."*

*"If a system that is not in equilibrium is analyzed on the basis of a
thermodynamic formalism predicated on the supposition of equilibrium,
inconsistencies appear in the formalism and predicted results are at
variance with experimental observations."*

*"The single, all-encompassing problem of thermodynamics is the determination of the equilibrium state that eventually results after the removal of
internal constraints in a closed, composite system."*

As you note, in thermodynamics we tend to classify energy transfer into heat transfer, mass transfer, and work. The energy transfer between the motor and the gas through the rotating paddle isn't heat transfer because it isn't driven by a temperature difference. And it's obviously not mass transfer. So is it work?

Sometimes it's easy to define work as any energy transfer that's not heat or mass transfer. We expect work—like heat and mass transfer—to be amenable to modeling with conjugate terms: a generalized force and a generalized displacement, the product of which corresponds to the transferred energy. This seems to apply straightforwardly here: the generalized displacement is the angular displacement, and the generalized force is just the resistive force from fluid drag.

I believe Callen's point is that he doesn't accept this resolution because the drag is a speed-dependent phenomenon; it doesn't arise in quasistatic conditions—that is, equilibrium conditions. If the paddle is rotated very, very slowly, it kicks a little momentum to atoms striking the leading edge but pulls some away from atoms striking the tailing edge. Turbulence and dissipation are essentially absent. This is totally unlike the case of compressing a gas with a piston, in which the work converges to a constant and notably nonzero value as the rate goes to zero to obtain the quasistatic state that he maintains as crucial to accurate analysis.

Comment: Hmm. From other textbooks (namely the ones by Rau and Reif) I am used to thinking of work as being any energy transfer in which a control parameter (entering the Hamiltonian) of the system is being changed; obviously, this viewpoint isn't even defined in Callen's postulatory approach but I guess I don't see why he doesn't define work in general in some analogous way and then define heat as any energy transfer (with no mass transfer) which is not work. Perhaps I didn't understand your resolution to that question in your answer -- I will have to read it again.

Answer (score 3):

You can trace the apparent difficulty with Callen's description to that by his concentrating on the "system" he separates the source of the energy transfer from the system on which work is done. His (or Tisza's) "thermodynamics" is really "thermostatics" in the sense that it is only interested *mathematically* what it takes to move from one equilibrium state to another infinitesimally close to it. But there are other ways of approaching the subject by which your question can be satisfactorily answered.

You start by observing that *all* thermodynamic works are of two kinds: (1) a conserved or semi-conserved quantity/charge/mass is moved from one potential to another and doing work $\delta w = \delta Y \delta X$ , or (2) in an external field a nonconserved quantity is created by doing work $\delta w = Y\delta X$.

Examples for cases (1) and (2):

1. temperature - entropy; (this is the only "semi-conserved", ie., never decreasing quantity)
2. electric potential - electric charge;
3. gravitational potential-gravitational mass;
4. chemical potential - mole number;
5. hydrostatic pressure - volume;
6. stress - strain, etc.

---

1. electric field - dipole density;
2. magnetic field - magnetic dipole density;
3. surface tension - surface area, etc.

Ignoring now case (2) the conservation of work principle states that for *reversible * processes in which the system exchanges with its environment in the $k^{th}$ work interaction a "charge" $\delta X_k$ while said charge is moved over a potential difference $\delta Y_k$ the *total work* is zero:
$$\sum_k \delta  w_k = \sum_k \delta Y_k \delta X_k = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
You could view $\eqref{1}$ as the operational definition of a *reversible process*. There is no requirement that the quantities in $\eqref{1}$ be infinitesimal only that as the charges $\delta X_k$ are moved from potential level $Y_k^1$ to level $Y_k^2$ with $\delta Y_k = Y_k^1- Y_k^2$, these potentials not change during the transport.

If, on the other hand, the process is *not* reversible then, by definition, the total work is not zero $\sum_kw_k\ne 0$, it is never negative and it must be *positive*:

$$\sum_k \delta  w_k = \sum_k \delta Y_k \delta X_k = \delta q^* = T\delta S^* >0\tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $\delta S^* > 0$ is the irreversibly generated entropy at temperature $T$. That is all.

Now let us see how this approach could handle your question. Neither the paddle in the viscous fluid nor the viscous fluid is moved from one potential to another but the electrons moving the motor moving the paddle have been moved across an electric  potential drop (battery) or as in Joule's experiment a mass on string drops in gravitational field, and their work is in the sum of $\eqref{2}$ and the corresponding $\delta q^*$ is the irreversibly generated (evolved) heat by said process. (To state this you do not even need energy conservation only reversible work conservation and irreversible entropy generation.)