Distinguish a reversible process via measurements
Is it possible to distinguish between reversible and irreversible processes - say, the process of the working substance in a heat engine - via a measurement?
Its a bad question, in the sense that reversible processes don't actually exist, but on the other hand we might want to show via measurement that the process is irreversible - which it is in reality. I think the answer should of course be: no. The equilibrium conditions for a reversible process are too strict.

Think about the conditions that  make a process more or less reversible and how you could identify those conditions by making measurements.

It is not a bad question at all, in fact, it is possible to distinguish irreversibility from reversibility; here are two posts on the subject https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773545/meaning-of-thermodynamic-identity/773586#773586 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/763179/on-definitions-of-interactions-in-thermodynamics-changing-the-energy-of-a-closed/763191#763191
